# Feature selection in survival data using mRMRe package in r

Tags: r, feature-selection, survival-analysis

I am in search of few feature selection methods for survival data in r. I want to use Maximum Relevance and Minimum Redundancy for the said task. In vignette of the package mRMRe, it mentioned they accept Survival data for the MIM and variable selection. But I couldn't found any useful example to help me do the feature selection.

If someone could please write down the exact code for feature selection in survival analysis using mRMRe package please.

I tried a simple example from the vignette but that didn't worked for me as dataset used was not of survival type.